# presentViewController from TabBarController to outside

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

Here is my main StoryBoard:

[image: Storyboard]

As you can see there is a main TabBarController, but in Order to see the TabBarController user has to login first in (LoginViewController which is outside of main TabBarController this is the code in viewDidLoad of all my controllers in TabBar:

```
    if ( ![Client isLoggedIn] ) {
         UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:Nil];
         UIViewController* loginView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginScene"];
         [self.navigationController presentViewController:loginView animated:YES completion:nil];
         return;
    }
```

but sometimes(!) this doesn't work at all and application hangs (and when it happens even uninstalling the application doesn't help)

What is the correct way to redirect user from TabBarController to another ViewController (LoginViewController) in this case, which is not a child of TabBarController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could connect your separate `NavigationViewController` as a `manual modal segue` to the `TabbarController`. 
Set an `identifier` to the segue, then you can use this code:

```
if ( ![Client isLoggedIn] ) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MyModalSegue" sender:self];
}
```

This should work properly. In addition, you get the modal animation for free.

Answer (score 0):

Just try replace

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:loginView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

with

```
[self presentViewController:loginView animated:YES completion:nil];
```